# ACPI Errors: What do they mean and how to handle them?

Tags: boot, acpi, bios

There are some ACPI errors on my system journal, I feel a need to find what causes them to occur.

Here are the errors, which appear before NetworkManager and sddm start:

```
Aug 05 11:50:26 mymachine kernel: [drm] size 5324800
Aug 05 11:50:26 mymachine kernel: [drm] fb depth is 24
Aug 05 11:50:26 mymachine kernel: [drm]    pitch is 5888
Aug 05 11:50:26 mymachine kernel: fbcon: radeondrmfb (fb0) is primary device
Aug 05 11:50:26 mymachine kernel: Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 180x56
Aug 05 11:50:26 mymachine kernel: radeon 0000:00:01.0: fb0: radeondrmfb frame buffer device
Aug 05 11:50:26 mymachine kernel: ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve [\_SB.ALIB], AE_NOT_FOUND (20180313/psargs-330)
Aug 05 11:50:26 mymachine kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.VGA.ATC0, AE_NOT_FOUND (20180313/psparse-516)
Aug 05 11:50:26 mymachine kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.VGA.ATCS, AE_NOT_FOUND (20180313/psparse-516)
Aug 05 11:50:26 mymachine kernel: [drm] Initialized radeon 2.50.0 20080528 for 0000:00:01.0 on minor 0
Aug 05 11:50:26 mymachine kernel: [drm] amdgpu kernel modesetting enabled.
Aug 05 11:50:26 mymachine sddm[500]: Adding new display on vt 1 ...
Aug 05 11:50:26 mymachine sddm[500]: Loading theme configuration from ""
Aug 05 11:50:26 mymachine sddm[500]: Display server starting...
```

**Motherboard:** MSI fm2+ a68hm-e33 v2
**CPU+GPU:** AMD A10 7890K
**OS:** Arch Linux

Comment: You've got some hardware that ACPI doesn't recognize (and cannot configure).

Comment: I have very similar to your 3 ACPI lines, mine's a Gigabyte F2A88XM-DS2 with AMD A8-7600; I'm running Kubuntu 18.04.2. I've had these errors for a while, they don't seem to be critical.